# How can I deploy my war file to IBM MFP container in Bluemix and also need to know the charges

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I am exploring the IBM MobileFirst Platform containers and I was successfully able to create an MFP container and I am able to see the wishlist application deployed by default to this container . Now If I want to to deploy my own war file in this server, how do i proceed? Also What are the charges for the bluemix containers as we have some external clients whose MFP is running in IMI server and we would like that to be moved to the bluemix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now If I want to to deploy my own war file in this server what should I do?

If you want to deploy your own .war file with your apps and your adapters, you need to create the container image yourself. As an IBM Customer your have access to the scripts you will need to use in order to take your local MobileFirst Studio/CLI project and move it "to the cloud".

See this tutorial: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/ibm-containers/run/

Comment: Thanks for your response.Also is there any way to change the context path of the sample image? and can we use that container image for production app or it is only for showing demo as how it looks?

Comment: The container provided is not meant for production; you cannot alter it.

Comment: For information on pricing, you can see this page: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

@gopi nath for moving your customers to Bluemix - you need to download the continer zip file with scripts (the link Idan gave above) from Passport Advandage and apply the latest iFix. The Container image in the bluemix container catalog is just for demo and cannot / should not be modified for production usage.